# Multiple classes wrapped to one Main

Tags: python, oop

I have written individual programs that need to be wrapped in one program, instead of one long code file. There is a detector and a recognizer, and the main program is responsible for taking an image, passing through detector, then making some image manipulations before passing it to the recognizer.

I have three files in the same location: **main.py**, **program1.py** and **program2.py**. These programs also contains functions.

I want to use these .py files in the main as following:

```
import program1, program2
import skimage.io
import numpy as np

image_path = "abc"
image = skimage.img_as_float(skimage.io.imread(image_path)).astype(np.float32)

# program 1 will load the image and detect objects in it, returning a pandas dataframe
detected = program1(image)

# For each object in dataframe, crop image and run recognizer
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    object = image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax] #crop object from main image
    object_det = program2(object) #pass cropped object to recognizer
    print(object_det) # program2 will return a string
```

**My question:** *Should I create classes for both Program1 and Program2 ? or should I create them as functions, then import them ? They have multiple dependencies on external libraries.*

Can someone tell me what is the most effective and Pythonic way to go about this problem ?

Comment: Doing with a Class would be the best approach

Answer (score 1):

When you do `import program1, program2` in `main.py`, you get `program1` and `program2` variables in your namespace. Those are module objects, who's attributes will be the global variables defined in your other files (including functions defined at the top level). You can't directly call a module object, which is what your current code is doing.

So rather than:

```
detected = program1(image)
```

You should do something like:

```
detected = program1.some_function(image)
```

Where `some_function` is the name of whatever function you defined in the `program1` file. Similarly:

```
    object_det = program2(object) #pass cropped object to recognizer
```

Should probably be:

```
    object_det = program2.some_other_function(object) #pass cropped object to recognizer
```

Whether you should use classes or not is really a separate design decision from getting the imports working. If a simple function call is an appropriate interface for what each of your two modules does with the data you'd be sending it, than there's no need to add on a complicated OOP structure just for style's sake. But if you have more complicated stuff to do than you've shown in your example, it might make sense to write one or more classes. Without more information though, it's impossible for us to give more detailed suggestions.